# Make a lookup table from a data.frame

Tags: r, hash

I have a `data.frame` which has only one unique non-`NA` value in all columns but one, which only has `NA`.

```
data <- data.frame(A = c("egg", "egg"), B = c(NA, "bacon"), C = c("ham", "ham"), D = c(NA, NA))
```

How can I use it to create a lookup table of the form below?

```
lookup <- make_lookup(key=unique_values(data), value=names(data))
lookup[["egg"]] # returns "A"
lookup[["bacon"]] # returns "B"
lookup[["ham"]] # returns "C"
lookup[["NA"]] # returns "D"
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on Frank's answer below, I'm trying to have my lookup table refer to multiple values.

```
keys <- lapply(data, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) levels(x) else "bacon")
vals <- names(data)
```

> keys

```
$A
[1] "egg"

$B
[1] "bacon"

$C
[1] "ham"

$D
[1] "bacon"
```

> vals

```
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

> tapply(vals, keys, c)

```
Error in tapply(vals, keys, c) : arguments must have same length
```

Comment: Please show what `lookup` should look like.

Comment: @Frank: every entry in the list should be shown in the code. I was imagining this might be a good use for the `hash` package.

Comment: Try `mlt <- unique(melt(as.matrix(data))[-1]);split(mlt$Var2, mlt$value)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way. The lookup is a vector:

```
keys <- sapply(data,function(x)if(is.factor(x))levels(x)else "NA")
vals <- names(data)

lookup <- setNames(vals,keys)
```

I've replace `NA` with `"NA"` since I couldn't figure out how to use the former.

The syntax `lookup[["egg"]]` works, but also `lookup["egg"]`. The reverse lookup is `rlookup <- keys`, accessible the same way: `rlookup["A"]`.

---

**For keys with multiple values.** If the keys may map to a vector of values, use

```
lookup <- tapply(vals,keys,c)
```

Try this out with `keys <- sapply(data,function(x)if(is.factor(x))levels(x)else "bacon")` and `vals` as above, for example (as in the OP's comment, below). Now the lookup is a list and so can only be accessed with double brackets: `lookup[["bacon"]]`. The reverse lookup works as before.

---

**For general column classes.** If the columns of `data` are not all factors, the `if`/`else` conditions will need to be modified or generalized. Here is a version of @akrun's generalized solution from the comments:

```
keys <- sapply(data,function(x)c(unique(as.character(x)[!is.na(x)]),"NA")[1])
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Wrapping with `hash(lookup)` creates the hash version I was thinking about. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, good find. I just realized that my answer does not work for `NA` as a key. I see that `hash(lookup)` has the same problem. You probably want to come up with a different convention for that case, like using the string `"NA"`. -- Edited that into the answer.

Comment: melt, hash, eggs, ham, bacon.  All we need is cheese and it's time for lunch!

Comment: Following this example, I actually changed "NA" to "bacon" in the if statement. How can I modify your code so the lookup for "bacon" returns `c("B", "D")`?

Comment: @wdkrnls `tapply` should work there. I've edited that into the answer.

Comment: @Frank Nice, I was also thinking about a direct `tapply`, but the real `NAs` created trouble.

Comment: @Frank: I can't get `tapply` to work: `tapply(vals, keys, c)
Error in tapply(vals, keys, c) : arguments must have same length`

Comment: @wdkrnls Hm, I guess `keys` is too long. Maybe you have multiple factor levels in one of the columns? You can look at `length(keys)` and `length(vals)` to debug.

Comment: @wdkrnls Oh, I see. At some point, I switched `keys` from `lapply` to `sapply`. It still works with the latter here, for some reason.